# Code on my page stops code on page from running

Tags: javascript, replace, onload

I'm trying to get a script to replace text on my page with different text and a link.  Without the code, the page works fine and I'm able to do things like add to cart, lookup a product number (which is driven by a mouseover command), etc.  The code works fine, it replaces the text with a link, but when I have the code inserted, the page no longer runs any code following a user input (ie. lookup a product number).

Any idea why this breaks my page?

```
window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",Name,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",Name);
function Name(){
     if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText.indexOf("Text") > 
-1) {
      var Var1 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    var Var2 = Var1.replace(/Text/gi,"<a href = 
\"https://www.example.com\">NewText;</a>"); 
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = Var2;

}

}
```

I originally was using document.onload, I've tried window.onload, and several other event handlers, all of which also broke the page.  I read that appending onload is the proper way to do it, and have incorporated that into the code you see here, but none of these steps I've taken have solved the problem.

Comment: `function (){` this is a syntax error, you'll have to give that function a name. Something like `function funcNameHere(){`

Comment: Thanks Titus.  I had that in my original code, I just forgot to type it in when I was making everything generic for the forum.  I've edited my post and still have the problem.

Comment: You're using the function `Name` before you define it.

Comment: Put your code in here and you will see a few issues right off the mark. http://jshint.com/

Comment: Hi Titus,  I tried to include the event listeners after the function but it made no difference.  The code still works but the page stops working after it's loaded.

Comment: It seems that your code contains some other syntax errors, you can use the method suggested by @Yoda to try to fix them.

Comment: Hi Titus and Yoda,  Most of the syntax errors are caused by line breaks being inserted when I enter the code on the forum.  The only actual error I'm seeing is on line 3 (expected assignment or function call and instead saw an expression).  How do I fix that?

Comment: You can ignore that or put all the code from the first three lines on the same line.

Comment: Ok Thanks.  I went ahead and added the corrected code without any syntax errors and the page is still not running code after loading... I'm stumped on this because it seems like a pretty simple bit of code and it's in agreement with everything I've found about how this should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out replacing the innerHTML of the body prevents my page (for an unknown reason... this is a squarespace site) from running any code after load.  Hence, the above code worked (in spite of a few syntax issues), but broke the page.

I fixed this by targeting more specific elements on the page by class, which took some guess and check to find the right one that contained my element (again, it's hard to decipher squarespace), but everything is working fine now.

Working code:

```
window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",FuncName,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",FuncName);
function FuncName(){
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.indexOf("word") > -1) 
{
      var Var1 = document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName');    
       for (var i = 0; i < Var1.length; i++){
    var Var2 = document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[i].innerHTML;
    var Var3 = Var2.replace(/word/gi,"<a href = 
\"http://www.example.com\">NewWord</a>"); 
    document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[i].innerHTML = 
Var3;
```

I've had to add a loop to cover the multiple instances of the word I'm looking for in different classes, but there you go.  Hope this helps someone stuck on a similar problem.